# Salesforce PushTopic NotifyForFields if element in where

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have a pushTopic in Salesforce, and that listens to some fields

`SELECT Id, f1, f2 FROM InvoiceStatement__c`

And what I'd really like is a way to say something like:

`SELECT Id, f1, f2 FROM InvoiceStatement__c WHERE f2 changed`

This way I'd only be sent a notification when the field f2 changed, which is the only field I really care about, I just need the others for some bookkeeping.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference only the fields that you want to be notified in your query SELECT:

`SELECT f2 FROM InvoiceStatement__c`

If you don't want to be notified about the other fields, you need to remove them from your push topic query and perform a new query when you are notified.